# Unity3D Strafing Left & Right

Tags: c#, unity

I am trying to set my character up to strafe left and right and have 2 different animations, on for left and one for right, so far what i have written allows me to strafe left or right but it only ever plays the right strafe animation. What am i doing wrong?

```
private void Strafe() {
    if (Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Strafe")) > 0) {
        animation.CrossFade ("strafeRight");
        _controller.SimpleMove(_myTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * Input.GetAxis ("Strafe") * strafeSpeed);
    } else if (Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Strafe")) < 0) {
        animation.CrossFade ("strafeLeft");
        _controller.SimpleMove(_myTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * Input.GetAxis ("Strafe") * strafeSpeed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right after i posted this i realized i was using MathF.Abs... No Need for that lol. here is correct code and works fine now!

```
private void Strafe() {
    if ((Input.GetAxis ("Strafe")) > 0) {
        animation.CrossFade ("strafeRight");
        _controller.SimpleMove(_myTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * Input.GetAxis ("Strafe") * strafeSpeed);
    } else if ((Input.GetAxis ("Strafe")) < 0) {
        animation.CrossFade ("strafeLeft");
        _controller.SimpleMove(_myTransform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * Input.GetAxis ("Strafe") * strafeSpeed);
    }
}
```